# Rankin no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query, classificação

Estou tentando gerar um ranking de faltas pra o RH.

O registro das faltas é feito em uma tabela separada do cadastro do Funcionário.
Eu preciso trazer a lista de funcionários ativos e a quantidade de faltas que ele já teve na empresa, só que quero ordenar do funcionário que teve mais faltas para o que teve menos.

Fiz o SQL abaixo, mas traz somente os funcionários que tiveram faltas:

```
select rh.NOME_FUNCIONARIO, COUNT(registro_faltas_atraso.CPF) as Total from RH 
JOIN registro_faltas_atraso
on  registro_faltas_atraso.CPF =rh.cpf
where 
rh.TIPO_CONTRATO !='Dispensado'
GROUP BY rh.NOME_FUNCIONARIO
ORDER BY desc total
```

Comment: use o LEFT JOIN que trará todos os registros da primeira tabela, no caso a rh

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      RH.NOME_FUNCIONARIO
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN RFA.CPF IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total 
FROM        RH 
LEFT JOIN   registro_faltas_atraso RFA ON RFA.CPF = RH.cpf
WHERE       RH.TIPO_CONTRATO != 'Dispensado'
GROUP BY    RH.NOME_FUNCIONARIO
ORDER BY    Total DESC
```

Comment: Tem toda a razão! Resposta editada. Obrigado.